# How to refactor my code, so the h2 header renders only when needed?

Tags: reactjs

I have simple react component where I render a list of hotels. I fetch data from firebase. I added a statement which I want to render ONLY when there aren't any hotels on list. Currently this h2 tag renders every time when I refresh the browser, or click on the go back button. Could you please kindly advise how can I make it to render only when needed?

```
import { DocumentData, onSnapshot, QuerySnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { hotelsCollection } from "../lib/controller";
import { NewHotelType } from "../types/hotel";
import Information from "./Information";

function Hotel() {
  const [hotels, setHotels] = useState<NewHotelType[]>([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("")
  const [sortState, setSortState] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(
    () =>
      onSnapshot(hotelsCollection, (snapshot: QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>) => {
        setHotels(
          snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
            return {
              id: doc.id,
              ...doc.data(),
            };
          })
        );
      }),
    []
  );

  if(isLoading) return <div>Loading..</div>

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <select
        className="select"
        defaultValue={""}
        onChange={(e) => setSortState(e.target.value)}
      >
        <option value="disabled">Filter By</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
        <option value="price">Price</option>
      </select>
      <div className="search">
        <input
          className="inputsearch"
          value={search}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search for the hotel"
          onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      {hotels && hotels.length ? (
        <div>
          {hotels
            ?.filter((item: NewHotelType) => {
              if (search === "" && !search.length) {
                return item;
              }
              return item?.title === search;
            })
            .sort((a, b) => {
              if (sortState === "name") {
                if (a.title && b.title) return a.title.localeCompare(b.title);
              }
              if (sortState === "price") {
                return Number(a.perNight) - Number(b.perNight);
              }
              return 0;
            })
            ?.map((hotel: NewHotelType) => (
              <Information key={hotel.id} hotel={hotel} />
            ))}
        </div>
      ) : !isLoading ? (
        <h2 className="no-hotels">There are no hotels. Please add one</h2>
      ) : <div>Loading..</div>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Hotel;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is correct. What you need, is to manage the loading state as well. When your component first renders your hotels state is an empty array, so till it gets filled by the data, you need to show a Loader, that way you make sure that the title is only rendering when the array is empty and the data has finished loading.

One way of doing it, is having a loading state that you set initially to true. and once your snapshot is successful and you pushed the data to the state, you will set the loading to false. In other words, after setHotels(...) you want to setLoading to false.

Now in your JSX you want to add a short circuit for the loading state,eg: `if(loading) return <Loader />`

Update:

```
function Hotel() {
  const [hotels, setHotels] = useState<NewHotelType[]>([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [sortState, setSortState] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(
    () =>
      onSnapshot(hotelsCollection, (snapshot: QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>) => {
        setHotels(
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
            return {
              id: doc.id,
              ...doc.data(),
            };
          })
        );
        setIsLoading(false)
      }),
    []
  );

  if (isLoading) return <div>Loading..</div>;

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <select
        className="select"
        defaultValue={""}
        onChange={(e) => setSortState(e.target.value)}
      >
        <option value="disabled">Filter By</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
        <option value="price">Price</option>
      </select>
      <div className="search">
        <input
          className="inputsearch"
          value={search}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search for the hotel"
          onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      {hotels && hotels.length ? (
        <div>
          {hotels
            ?.filter((item: NewHotelType) => {
              if (search === "" && !search.length) {
                return item;
              }
              return item?.title === search;
            })
            .sort((a, b) => {
              if (sortState === "name") {
                if (a.title && b.title) return a.title.localeCompare(b.title);
              }
              if (sortState === "price") {
                return Number(a.perNight) - Number(b.perNight);
              }
              return 0;
            })
            ?.map((hotel: NewHotelType) => (
              <Information key={hotel.id} hotel={hotel} />
            ))}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <h2 className="no-hotels">There are no hotels. Please add one</h2>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you please show me excatly where I need to render this in my jsx ? I have added state const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);, but can't figure out where I should render this

Comment: You have 2 options, either you keep your current return as it is, and add another one above it like this `if (isLoading) return <div>Whatever you want to display on loading</div>, or you can change your code to something like {!isLoading ? <h2 className="no-hotels">There are no hotels. Please add one</h2> : "Whatever you want to show on loading"}

Comment: @Emilia I will update my answer with both options

Comment: Hello, I updated my code as well with you suggestion, however it does not solve my problem. ALso I keep getting error on setIsLoading not used for both options  :( Could you please double check and advise? It looks like my <h2 className="no-hotels">There are no hotels. Please add one</h2> is rendering every time when refreshing

Comment: When you component initialize, isLoading should be true. Your code should be like this const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true), and then you call setIsLoading(false) from within your snapshot after setHotels({...))

Comment: @Emilia I updated my answer with the changes you need to make!

Comment: Thank you, this finally works as expected :)